# Escaping Parameter Query Delimeter

Tags: javascript, php, escaping

I was wondering what would be the best way of escaping `^` symbol which is what I am using as delimiter in a query parameter, shown below:

```
sysparm_query=active=true^first_nameSTARTSWITHpete^r^last_nameENDWITHxxxx
```

At the moment, if I split this by `^`, I will get a 4-member array, which is obviously incorrect.

Would you use a backslash, percent encoding to escape `^` in a field value?

Comment: Why is it incorrent, if this query will be splitted into 4 parts?

Comment: I think a better question would be *why are you even doing this in the first place?* ... it's like reinventing the wheel and deciding a pentagon would be a better shape.

Comment: @Bfcm i expect to get the following key-value pairs after splitting the string by ^: active=true, first_nameSTARTSWITHpeter^, last_nameENDSWITHxxx. However, since ^ is not escaped after "peter", it will be confused for a delimiter, which is not.. so how would one escape it ?

Comment: I'm assuming you are constructing the query parameter in javascript to submit to PHP. If so, you can avoid using a delimiter by using a query string like "sysparm_query[]=foo&sysparm_query[]=bar". In PHP, $_REQUEST['sysparm_query'] will be an array('foo', 'bar'), and you won't need to split by your magic character.